# Understanding remark after theorem 5.5.13 in Spanier AT

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In Spanier AT, after theorem 5.5.13, it says that

> Note that if the s.e.s. of theorem 10 is valid for a given $C$ for all $G$, then the hypothesis of theorem 13 is satisfied, and so $H(C)$ is of finite type.

I don't know why this is true. Here's theorem 10 and theorem 13.

> Theorem 10. Let $C$ be a free chain complex and $G$ be a module such that either $H(C)$ is of finite type or $G$ is finitely generated. Then there is a functorial s.e.s.
> $$\boxed{0\to H^q(C;R)\otimes G\xrightarrow{\mu}H^q(C;G)\to H^{q+1}(C;R)*G\to 0}$$
> and this sequence splits.

> Theorem 13. Let $C$ be a free chain complex such that for every module $G$ the map $\mu:Hom(C,R)\otimes G\to Hom(C,G)$ induces isomorphisms of all cohomology modules. Then $H_*(C)$ is of finite type.

How the s.e.s. of theorem 10 implies $\mu$ is an isomorphism?

Comment: What does $\ast$ denote in $H^{q+1}(C; R)\ast G$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese $A*B:=\operatorname{Tor}_1(A,B)$